# monaco-editor get hovered content between delimiters

Tags: monaco-editor

I have a hover provider and I need to provide dynamic content based on the text I'm hovering.
I should only return content, if the text hovered is surrounded by quotes (`"`), for example `"hoverThis"` or `"hover_this"`.

My problem is that when doing `model.getWordAtPosition()`, if the hovered text has word delimiters (for example: `"hover.this"` or `"hover this"`), I only get part of the content.

If I do `model.findPreviousMatch('"')` to get the previous and next quote, the search algorithm will loop to the end/beginning of the whole content and match the incorrect text, and even if it worked, it wouldn't guarantee I'm not hovering a word in between two quoted strings (for example: `"one quote" hover >< here and "another quote"`).

I'm looking for something like:
`model.getValueAtPosition(position, openDelimiters, closeDelimiters)`

to be used in my case like:
`model.getValueAtPosition(position,['"'], ['"'])`

what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You have a position, so why not scanning backwards and forwards from that in the content until you find the delimiters? Nothing else does `getWordAtPosition`.

Comment: This is my fallback option (which I already have working). I have 2 concerns: 1 is that using findPreviousMatch will loop back through the model until the start position or match found, which is not great (it produces a match after the hovered position a lot of times, which I can still check for that and validate, but still). And 2, if I just do a string scan manually, feels a bit odd since there's a whole language model behind the editor to then have to manually traverse the string?

Comment: Also thinking about it, it is quite common for a language to have bits in between constraints, like quoted text, or arrays, js objects, html tags, so maybe a method like "findConstrainedValueAtPosition({ line: 1, column: 25 }, '(', ')')" sounds very useful